# SSRS 2005 parameters dimensions

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I was wondering if there anyway to manipulate the position and size of the text boxes for the parameters in SSRS 2005. They generally take up a large part of the top of the page and I want to prevent that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the out of the box Report Manager. You might be able to achieve some control by tweaking the style sheet.

if you just need to control parameter order they will be rendered in the order they are defined in the designer.

you could probably create an html page that is a front end to the report and then set the parameters via URL access.

more info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153563.aspx